# how to add "goto definition" in vs2012 and c++ project using "Ctrl+Click"

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-assist-x

I do have such code in my .c file:

```
#define CHECK_FAIL(f) \
{ \
    uint32_t res = f; \
    if (res != CG_ERR_OK) \
    { \
        log_info("Client gate error: %x", res); \
        exit(1); \
    } \
} 
....

CHECK_FAIL(env_open(ini_string));
```

I have VS2012 + VisualAssistX installed.
However when I "Ctrl+Click" the "CHECK_FAIL" nothing happens. But I expect VS to go to definition, how to do that?

There is "Alt + G" shortcut in VisualAssistX, but I really want to do that by mouse (using Ctrl+Click) and in VS I can not assign mouse as shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Visual Assist X Options dialog, on the `Advanced | General` page, you can check "Execute Goto upon Ctrl+Left-Click in text editor" to invoke the same command as the Alt+G keybinding.